# Solving $\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2}\text{d}x$ using residues.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

How can you evaluate the following integral using residues?
$$\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{\left(x^2+4\right)^2}\text{d}x$$

Comment: Replace $\log(x)$ by $\log^2(x)$ and integrate the resulting function around a keyhole contour in complex plane